# Get a managed bean reference in a restful web service

Tags: java, jsf, rest, asynchronous, managed-bean

i'm tryng to combine jsf and Rest in my web application.
My managed bean(eager=true) starts with the application, gets async data from an external api and adds this data into a List.

I have to make a restful web service that returns this list. How can i get this list? Can i obtain an instance of my ManagedBean outside the context?

However i'm not sure of this structure but i don't know other methods to get anynchronous data

Comment: You can consume the RESTful services form Java code and then passing the results through your managed beans.

Comment: i have to obtain asynch data at the begin of application
the i get this data through rest

Answer (score 2):

This is not the right approach. A JSF managed bean is intented to act as a controller for a JSF view, not as a business service. You should make use of a business service API which can be shared by all kinds of front-ends (JSF, JAX-RS, etc). Such an API is already offered by Java EE: EJB. Replace that eagerly initialized application scoped managed bean by a `@Startup @Singleton` EJB which you can inject everywhere (your JSF managed bean and your JAX-RS webservice) via `@EJB`.

Comment: thank you.. I suspected it
then i have to use a startup bean, instead of using a managed bean, to receive asynchrounous data. Then i can access the bean from my webservice to obtain the resource i want.. right?

however.. thank you again